# jScrollPane maintainPosition

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

There is a setting in jScrollPane maintainPosition, but according to my testing this doesnt work (its true by default). After reinitializing it always scrolls to top.

I have a vertical scrollbar with boxes inside all 100px in height (for easy math).

Now lets say I have scrolled somewhere, and after I add or remove couple of boxes anywhere in the line, I want for it maintain at the same position.

I can use getPercentScrolledY option, and then re-apply it later with scrollToPercentY, but this will save the position of the scrollbar.

What I want is that the same box(es) that was visible remains at the same position after adding or removing boxes (unless that box was removed) in which case I want it somewhere closest.

Can anybody calculate that?